# How to check if current phones date is today or not

Tags: java, android, date

In android I use this code to get the current date:

```
String phone_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

It will display `2019-03-05` Asia Time Basis.

If I go to settings of my phone and change it to `2019-03-04`, the code above will give me the same.

How can I check if the date is today? I found solutions that mostly requires net but my app is offline.

Is there any way to check it, like compare it to phones internal date?

Comment: I think you need to check it online to guarantee time is correct

Comment: Your in a locked room with nothing in the room (no windows, no phone signal, no WIFI, no GPS) except a phone. The phone may have been messed with by a hacker and it might not be the right date for your location. By what means do you find the the correct date ? This is essentially what you have asked.

Comment: @JonGoodwin basically ur right :(

Comment: but gps will not be on also :(

Comment: I think there is no option if you are offline and not rely on system date.

Comment: You could keep your own clock time in a foreground service, so you could ignore tampering by a hacker of the system clock, but if you reboot your phone, your are back where you started. The only option is to blow the bloody doors off... ;O)

Comment: maybe i will just keep this post here maybe in future someone will answer it. thnx for telling the truth even if it hurts :(

Comment: Your app is offline, but the time is really required by your app? if yes, then why not just check if the Date and Time is Automatically set or not.

Comment: @dotGitignore time is not required on my app just only the date